Why torch cuda counting on cpu?
I am training a model and my torch.device('cuda' if torch.code.is_available() else 'cpu') outputs a code. But the task manager shows a gpu load of 0%, and a CPU load of 35 - 40%.To install torch, I used pip install torch==2.3.1 torchvision==0.18.1 torchaudio==2.3.1 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121

Your CPU still needs to do work executing python code and sending data to and from the GPU. Your workload is probably too small to show up in the GPU performance graph. Try making your batch size a lot larger

Did you use the nvidia-smi command? If your code resides in the GPU, then the command would display the information with the process ID and the memory occupied by the model as shown here,
sample output of nvidia-smi command
